# How can I get Textmate to properly highlight the code in Ruby .rb files?

Tags: ruby, textmate, textmatebundles

I am using version 1.5.15 (1523) of Textmate on OX X Snow Leopard. My .rb files only have rudimentary highlighting, and the highlighting breaks on every appearance of a double-quoted string. The syntax has been checked and it is valid.

How can I fix the code highlighting for .rb files. It's almost as if it doesn't know it's a Ruby file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have an `.rb` file open, make sure that the syntax/filetype is set to Ruby. In the "status bar" at the bottom of the window, to the right of the Line/Column numbers, you can click the file type and choose "Ruby" (it's probably set to something else).

After doing this, TextMate should remember that `.rb` files should use the Ruby type going forward.